# ServiceStack.Text JSON Deserialization

Tags: json, servicestack

The following json is given

```
{"pusher":{"fullName":"Me","email":"foo@fomail.biz","accesstoken":false},"repository":{"url":"https://ffff.com/Code/"},"commits":[{"id":"d83ee17aa40bc79b9f4dcdf58a099b424e08745b","revision":63,"branch":"default","tags":["tip"]}]}
```

Now i wanted to deserialize this json to an object. The class is defined as this:

```
 public sealed class KilnCommitPayload
    {
        public string branch { get; set; }

        public int revision { get; set; }
    }
```

and the deserialisation code ist :

```
var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<KilnCommitPayload>(content);
```

now I expected that branch would be "default" and revision would be 63

But both proeprties were not set. do you have any hint why and what I should change?

Comment: Those properties are inside commits array.

Comment: oh yes. thats it, I overlooked that. now it works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those properties are inside commits array. Your type should reflect your JSON data. You should have a model like this.

```
public class Payload
{
    public Pusher Pusher { get; set; } 
    public Repository { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<KilnCommitPayload> { get; set; }
}
```